# String membership in hash set time complexity

Tags: time-complexity, strings, sets, hash-tables

Given a string `s` and a hashset of strings `words`, what is the time complexity of the operation: `s in words`? Assume all strings have length `M`. My current guess is O(M) to compute the hash of `s`, O(1) to find that bucket in the hash table, and O(M*number of strings in the bucket) to compare the strings in the bucket and the `s` , so a total of O(M*number of strings in the bucket). Not assuming any fancy string comparison algorithms here--want to focus more on the other parts.

Comment: Analysis of hash tables depends a lot on the assumptions you want to make.  Do you want an analysis that will be useful in practice, or do you care more about theoretical worst-case behavior?  Can we make reasonable assumptions about the load factor of the hash table?  Can we use expected running time?  etc.

Comment: @D.W. Maybe we can consider various reasonable scenarios? Say both avg and worst case behavior? Yes i think we can make reasonable assumptions about the load factor--let's not assume it is very skewed. Let's also use expected running time, and maybe talk a little bit about scenarios in which the worst case occurs.